# VB6 Export To CSV: How to retain zero values

Tags: csv, vb6, export-to-csv

How can I retain zero values when exporting a csv file, if opened on notepad it works well, but when in excel it removes the zeroes. is there a way I can convert numbers to text in the code? eg. '4.1200' = 4.12

```
 Private Sub ExportToCSV()
  Me.progCashr.Value = 25
Static iNum
Dim iRow, iCol As Integer
Dim sText As String
Dim sPath As String
iNum = FreeFile()
Me.progCashr.Value = 50
With cd
    On Error GoTo errtrap
    .CancelError = True
    .Filter = "*.CSV|*.CSV"
    .ShowSave
    If FileExists(.FileName) Then
        If fMessageBox("", "Overwrite File?", "Yes", "No", 0, 1, True) = 1 Then
        Me.progCashr.Value = 100
            Open .FileName For Output As #iNum
            MsgBox ("Export Success!")
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Open .FileName For Output As #iNum

    End If

End With

With Grid1
    For iRow = 2 To .Rows - 1
        sText = ""
        For iCol = 1 To .Cols - 1
            sText = sText & Replace(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Text, ",", "") & ","
        Next iCol
        If sText <> "" Then
            sText = Left$(sText, Len(sText) - 1)
            Print #iNum, sText
        End If
    Next iRow

End With
MsgBox ("Export Success!")
Close #iNum
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: If it works fine in Notepad, then the problem is not in exporting the file. You need to set the cell formatting properly after opening it in Excel.

Comment: then i have to do it everytime I open a csv file?

Comment: Yes. Excel doesn't know how you want to see the data, so it uses the common settings. 4.12 and 4.1200 are identical values, so there's no need to display the last two zeros. If you want it differently, set the cell formatting for the column to do so.

Comment: To avoid having to do this every time you open a file, you can set the cell formatting on a template sheet to the way you want it.  Then open the csv file and copy its contents to the template sheet.  It might be just as easy to set a global cell format each time, though.

Comment: Thanks Everyone :)